# High availability sessions with PHP and Memcached failover

Tags: php, session, memcached

I'd like to create a pseudo high availability setup, but most importantly a scalable setup, where a variable number of (apache/php7) web servers can connect to two memcached instances to store and retrieve a PHP session; should one memcached instance go down, that's no problem because the other one can temporarily pick up the slack whilst the other is fixed. Nobody should be incorrectly logged out.

I chose Memcached instead of Redis etc. because it appears to offer an easier route to this functionality.

After much research and testing I've finally got PHP writing sessions to two servers running memcached. Unfortunately, killing one of the servers appears to just log out the user; there is no failover as expected despite the second server stilling being up and running and containing the user's session.

What am I doing wrong with the setup? I'm assuming it's something in the `/etc/php/7.2/mods-available/memcached.ini` file, so here it is, minus comments etc.

```
extension=memcached.so
memcached.serializer=php
memcached.sess_lock_wait_min = 100
memcached.sess_lock_retries = 100
memcached.sess_number_of_replicas = 1
memcached.sess_prefix = "session."
memcached.sess_randomize_replica_read = 1
memcached.sess_remove_failed_servers = 1
```

And here are the relevant bits in `php.ini`:

```
[Session]
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "10.0.0.1:11211,10.0.0.2:11211"
session.use_strict_mode = 1
session.use_cookies = 1
session.cookie_secure = 1
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_httponly = 1
session.serialize_handler = php
```

Note that I am using the `memcached` extension, not the `memcache`. I would try the latter, but I'd really like to know what I'm doing wrong rather than giving in.

I'm also interested in any general comments about the approach I am taking with this project.

Many thanks for any help you can offer in advance.

Comment: Sure it fails over. Instead of connecting to the first server that had all the existing session data it fails over to the second which doesn't. If you want something resilient you should not be using Memcached at all. Hell, if you read memcached's own recommendations you'd see that they don't recommend it for session storage _at all_. Use Redis: https://redis.io/topics/replication

Comment: @sammitch sorry, I think you must have misread; both servers contain the session data. Please provide a reference to the statement above about Memcached, as I haven’t read this before. I accept it’s not 100% resilient, but the chances of failure are very small and Redis would not solve these issues, except for when the servers came back online you’d still have sessions (which will be too much of a delay for most anyway).